# "Multi tiered parking lot/garage" vs. "multi story/storied parking lot/garage" vs. "multi level parking lot/garage" in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Are these terms current enough in AE to be used just about interchangeably in modern prose?

Comment: Usually, in my neck of the woods, a lot is an uncovered area on ground level of on the top of a multi-tiered structure. A covered structure for multiple cars is a garage. I call the stories "levels" - ground level, third-level, etc. I think any of the phrases you use are easily understood; in the city, I say *is there a parking garage nearby*? That seems to cover it.

Comment: @Susan how about a "parkade", a "parking ramp", and a "parking deck" for a parking garage? Are these terms you have ever heard of in your neck of the woods?

Comment: If you were in the city and asked for a parking lot, chances are you'd be given directions to a ground-level paved lot or a parking garage since it would be fairly clear to the "askee" that you were looking for a place to park your car, regardless of configuration, IMO.

Comment: I have not heard any of those terms being used (parkade, parking ramp nor parking deck) in the US Midwest.

Comment: @KristinaLopez how about the terms "multi tiered" and "multi story/storied for a multi level structure, does any of these terms sound familiar to you?

Comment: @NG, the ramp, to me, is the incline leading to another level. I'm not familiar with the other two.

Comment: Sure, in a description of the parking facility, it would most likely be described as a multi-tiered or multi-story structure.

Comment: @Susan Just FYI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-storey_car_park

Comment: Please see my newly added answer - at least one of your terms is currently used - found on my first try.  Color me chagrined! :-)

Comment: @NG - Hmm! Interesting! Though the pictures are familiar (is every parking garage poorly lit?), the terms are not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a parking garage in almost any sense if you have more than one level.  The other terms are not used in AE.

Answer (score 1):

I learned something new...***"parking deck"*** and ***"parking facility"*** are used in [this](http://www.naperville.il.us/downtownparking.aspx) description of available downtown parking in Naperville, IL, as American a city as you can imagine.

> **Top 10 Tips for Parking in Downtown Naperville**
>
> 1. Real-time parking availability for the Central Parking Facility and Van Buren Parking Deck is posted outside each of the parking decks.
> 2. The Municipal Center Parking Deck is available to all visitors after 5 p.m. Monday through Friday and all day during the weekend.
> 3. Check out Levels 2 and 3 of the Central Parking Facility for available parking spaces.
> 4. Overnight parking is permitted in the Van Buren Parking Deck (Levels 1 through 5), Central Parking Facility (Levels 1 and 2) and the Municipal Center Parking Deck (Lower Level) on Friday and Saturday nights.

Comment: I used to live near Naperville IL and never heard the term "Parking Deck" used.  It is probably a governmentese term to sound better than Garage, or to distinguish it from where Naperville keeps and maintains its own vehicles.

Comment: It's a new facility @Oldcat. There are two multi-tiered parking garages in Naperville now.

Comment: Sure, but outside the website I would imagine they are referred to as Garages and not Decks.

Comment: No argument there @oldcat.  I know I would call it a garage.

Comment: A friend of mine says parking deck. I think he specifically referring to the top level of a parking garage, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In the UK we don't generally use any variants involving **tier**, **deck**, or **lot**. There's a tendency to use *multi **-level*** rather than *multi-storey* if some (or especially, *all*) of the parking spaces are at or below ground level, but other than that they're pretty much interchangeable.